# How to add key-value-pair to each dictionary in a list

Tags: csv, ansible

I have to add a key and a value to a list which is read from a csv-file into a variable.

To explain it a bit better. First I load a list from a csv-file:

```yaml
- name: Load user list from csv
  community.general.read_csv:
    path: ../files/example-prod.csv
    delimiter: ','
  register: users
  delegate_to: localhost
```

When I look at the "users" variable I get the following output:

```json
"list": [
        {
            "firstName": "Max",
            "gid": "2002",
            "homedir": "example",
            "lastName": "Mustermann",
            "uid": "m.example"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Martin",
            "gid": "2002",
            "homedir": "staff",
            "lastName": "Muster",
            "uid": "martin.muster"
        }
    ]
```

Now I need to generate passwords for all users in the list. So I want to loop through the items and add a new key-value-pair to each item in the list.

The output that I want after the password creation loop is:

```json
"list": [
        {
            "firstName": "Max",
            "gid": "2002",
            "homedir": "example",
            "lastName": "Mustermann",
            "uid": "m.example",
            "password": "examplepassword"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Martin",
            "gid": "2002",
            "homedir": "staff",
            "lastName": "Muster",
            "uid": "martin.muster",
            "password": "examplepassword"
        }
    ]
```

...so I can read out the variables later.

How to accomplish this? I've read many things about how to do this with a dictionary, but since I'm using a list here, I could not find it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually getting a list of dictionaries from the `read_csv` module. The content of `"list"` is a list, but the elements in this list are dictionaries.

What you want to do is to add a key-value-pair to each dictionary.
Here is an example generating random passwords. See the [password-lookup documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/password_lookup.html) on details how it generates passwords:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    users: |
      {{ users.list | map('combine', { "password": "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null chars=ascii_lowercase,digits length=8') }}"}) }}

# this resolves the template added above and is required to avoid changing passwords on each resolve of users
- set_fact:
    users: "{{ users }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ users }}"
```

Explanation:

- `users.list` contains your list of users
- `map('combine', <dict>)` runs the `combine` filter on each dictionary in the input list (`users.list` in this case) and adds the contents of `<dict>` to it
- `{ "password": "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null chars=ascii_lowercase,digits length=8') }}"}` is the dictionary we combine each input-dictionary with
- `"password"` is the key, and the value is the lookup that is generating the password

Remark:
I use the multi-line string literal of yaml to avoid the quoting-hell.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! The only problem I have now is, that the password get generated each time I call the "users" value, although we are using "set_fact" here. Do you have any idea to generate the passwords only once and not everytime I use the list?

Comment: Yes, that is true, `set_fact` will do that for the current run, but the information will be lost afterwards. You should not store the password in clear-text, but if you want to do that, you can store the data in the CSV and do the password generation only if the passwords are not yet present. What you should actually use is the [user-module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html) and set `update_password` to `on_create`, so they are not overwritten when the user already exists.

Comment: Yes, but that is not my problem. When I run a debug.msg on your code, the password gets regenerated each time I call the value in the playbook, not the run of the playbook itself. I know that the information gets lost on a re-run but, that is not the problem. I want to reference the list multiple times in the playbook and everytime I do so, the passwords gets generated new. That's not what I want. I want to reference it multiple times and get the same password for each user. I need this, because I reference the list.password variable in multiple tasks.

Comment: Yes, I see, sorry, stupid mistake on my side, I updated the answer and fixed it; Wrapping it in `{{ }}` caused the whole string to end up as a value and it would get resolved as a jinja-template every time it was read. :D

Comment: Thanks! The password stays the same now. But now every user has the same password :D

Comment: Looks like my oh-so-elegant solution wasn't so elegant after all. I added a workaround to my answer. It works now.