# Generate random passwords for users and store them so they can be used later

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to generate random passwords for set of users, display those password and send them via email.
But after using it in the user module, and later trying to send it as email the password variable creates a new password string.

I want to either append the passwords to the user list.
This is what I have tried so far:

```yaml
  vars:
    USER_ID_details:
      - user_id: testid1
        real_full_name: TESTID_1
        groups: wheel
        email_id: abc@abc.com
      - user_id: randnme
        groups: wheel
        real_full_name: TESTID_2
        email_id: abc@abc.com
    id_pass: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=15 chars=ascii_letters') }}"

  - name: create Linux user as per specification
    user:
      name: "{{ item.user_id }}"
      password: "{{ id_pass | password_hash('sha512') }}"
    loop: "{{ USER_ID_details }}"
    when:
      - os_type == "RedHat"
  - name: Send the details of the user id and password to the email address
    mail:
      subject: "*Confidential: {{ item.user_id }} user id created on {{ affected_host }}"
      body: "Hello, User id {{ item.user_id }} created on server {{ affected_host }} \n password: {{ id_pass }}"
      to: "{{ item.email_id }}"
    loop: "{{ USER_ID_details }}"
```

Comment: can you add(or emphasis) what is the issue with your approach ? what is the error ? what is the problem statement ?

Comment: wanted to see how the random passwords for each user can be either appended to the user list dictionary or set_fact and use the passwords as a list and use them in user module and later in the email module to send email with password

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add key-value-pair to each dictionary in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67431252/how-to-add-key-value-pair-to-each-dictionary-in-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already generating a random password in your `id_pass` variable.
To generate a random password for every user, do this:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    USER_ID_details: | 
      {{ USER_ID_details | map('combine', { "password": "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null chars=ascii_lowercase,digits length=15') }}"}) }}

# you need this, otherwise you will see different passwords every time you read the list
- set_fact:
    USER_ID_details: "{{ USER_ID_details }}"
```

You will now have a field called `password` in every item of your list. You can use that to set the user's password and send it to them.

Comment: Nice! that worked perfectly!! I was trying multiple ways with the combine filter to add to dict. but it was not working.. haha after your answer it looks so simple now. Thanks much!!

Comment: I am getting this error now.. any idea how to fix this. "USER_ID_details": "<generator object do_map at 0x7fcf897f3230>  \n" for the map/combine filter

Comment: @Deepak Only one question should be discussed per post. Please post any further questions as new questions.

Comment: For me, the second task is not rendering the template in the `USER_ID_details` string... When I use `debug` on `USER_ID_details`, it just outputs the original list of dicts combined with the `password` attribute and the `lookup` template string. I instead used `copy` to output the variable of the template into a `.j2` file and used `set_fact: "{{ lookup('template', 'tmp.j2') }}"` to force the rendering.